# How to have tabcompletion for docker cp?

Tags: autocomplete, docker, copy, containers, host

I want to copy some files from my docker container to my host system using

```
docker cp container_id:/path/to/file/that/is/annoyingly/long/poit.foo ~/local/
```

I really would like there to be tabcompletion for the path. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Do you have docker bash completion in place? (as in https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/729c9a97822ebee2c978a322d37060454af6bc66/contrib/completion/bash/docker#L11-L16)

Comment: Found this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33495/34165  TL;DR is enable container as a sshfs mount point. Just seen who posted the question over there ;)